# C trying to fix infinite loop

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I have a function that gets an index value, puts it in an array. Then generates a new new random index using rand + srand(**key**). And it checks if the newly generated index is in array already, it will will keep on generating new index and checking until a unique value is generated.

The problem is that it works fine for small **keys**, but at longer keys it gets stuck in an infinite loop and can never find a unique value. Here's my code:

```
int getNewIndex(PPM *im, int index, int *visitedPixels, int *visitedPixelsIndex) {

    int i = 0;
    if(*visitedPixelsIndex == im->height) {
        perror("Cannot encode anymore: pixels limit reached");
        exit(1);
    }

    visitedPixels[*visitedPixelsIndex] = index;
    (*visitedPixelsIndex)++;
    // If index is already in the list, generate a new number and check again.
    while (i < *visitedPixelsIndex) {
        if(index == visitedPixels[i]) {
            index = rand() % im->height;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

EDIT: `im->height` which is the image height is about 400-600 in average.

Comment: What are "keys" that you mention?

Comment: It's an unsigned int. It could be any non-negative number. I use it as a seed for srand()

Comment: How do you handle the case where all values from 0 to (im->height - 1) is already in the array?

Comment: if visitedPixelsIndex == im->height . I should have named it visitedPixelsCounter

Comment: So what do you mean by "but at longer keys..." ? The word "longer" seems strange for an unsigned int

Comment: So it works fine for values like <10. But after that it just gets stuck at that loop.

Comment: But there is no code like `if visitedPixelsIndex == im->height`?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I removed the code quite a bit and accidentally removed that as well. I haven't slept in the past 30 hours trying to finish this assignment so my brain isn't functioning properly.

Comment: Hmm... so you are saying that, e.g. with `srand(8)` all is fine but with `srand(23765)` it will fail (with infinite loop)? That sounds strange - do you call `srand` more than once?

Comment: If all values from `0` to `im->height` are in your array there will be an infinite loop

Comment: OT but .... I would strongly recommend an ordinary `if` statement instead of `? :`

Comment: `visitedPixelsIndex == im->height` that is wrong! Should be `*visitedPixelsIndex == im->height`

Comment: @4386427 It's always a shame when they don't show us the whole function to begin with

Comment: I don't think all the values from 0 -> im->height can be in the list. The message is merely 10 letters in my testing. I'm converting each letter into 9 digit binary before encoding it into pixels. So at max I could have 10*9 out of 400 values/iterations.

I am calling srand twice but it is in two different functions so it is completely out of scope (I think)

Comment: @MitchelPaulin This is pretty much the whole function. Everytime I post a full function I get negative ratings for not posting MVCE. :(

Still the same issue after changing it to *visitedPixelsIndex.

Comment: Well, we can't help if you don't post more code. The best would be if you could post code that allowed us to reproduce the problem. It should be fairly easy to make a short `main` function with hard initialization of the variables.

Comment: Don't have an array for visited pixels. This is bad as you're essentially throwing a dart a a board blindfolded to try to find an unvisited one which is extremely slow. Have an array of *unvisited* pixels, choose randomly from the list then remove the value from the list. This way every choice is *guaranteed* to return an unvisited pixel. Having loops which have the possibility to run infinitely is bad design

Comment: Um... I'll have to post pretty much the whole code as this relies on encoding/decoding and that relies on getting the file, readinging through it, populating its values etc. Should I post it here?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Are you referring to Fisher-Yates Shuffle? I tried to implement that but I cannot do it :(

Comment: It doesn't have to be some special shuffle. Just randomly swap pixel indexes for a few thousand iterations. And loop through the list

Comment: Suggestion: rewrite your conditional operator expressions with simple `if`.

Comment: @pmg done. What's the beniefit for it? I have a lot of small if/else statements in my code so I did that to keep it short.

Comment: Do `im->height` have the **same** value in every call of this function?

Comment: It was a suggestion. In your code, for me, an `if` is very very much easier to grasp than the conditional operator. I like to keep the expressions in the conditional operator as simple as possible (and definitely not full statements as in your code).

Comment: @4386427 Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the code will generate an infinite loop when you insert the last free index into the array.

Assume that:

1) `im->height` is 500 so that valid index is in the range [0 .. 499]

2) You have already inserted 499 values, i.e. `*visitedPixelsIndex` is 499

So when the function is called this condition `*visitedPixelsIndex == im->height` will be false so you don't exit but continue on and you insert value number 500 in the array.

Then you do `(*visitedPixelsIndex)++;` so that `*visitedPixelsIndex` becomes 500.

After that you enter the `while` loop trying to find a new unused `index`. However - since you have already used all 500 valid index values, you'll never find an unused index.

In other words - **an infinite loop**

Maybe you should do:

```
(*visitedPixelsIndex)++;
if(*visitedPixelsIndex == im->height) {
    perror("Cannot encode anymore: pixels limit reached");
    exit(1);
}
```

I also think you should generate a new `index` **before** the `while` loop.

However, in general I think your code would be more clear if you split the current function into two functions. Like

```
int isPresent(int index, int *visitedPixels, int N) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        if (index == visitedPixels[i]) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getNewIndex(PPM *im, int index, int *visitedPixels, int *visitedPixelsIndex) 
{
    visitedPixels[*visitedPixelsIndex] = index;

    (*visitedPixelsIndex)++;

    if (*visitedPixelsIndex == im->height) {
        perror("Cannot encode anymore: pixels limit reached");
        exit(1);
    }

    do
    {
        index = rand() % im->height;
    } while(isPresent(index, visitedPixels, *visitedPixelsIndex));

    return index;
}
```

Comment: I just tested it and you're right, it is reaching the index limit. I'll try to fix it. Thank a lot.